# how to pass a callback function to a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

i have a php project which includes a few js files.
One of the js files, is a popup manager. This is the code:

```
function openYesNoPopup(message, callback) {
$('.popupBtn').unbind();

var popup_top = "<div class = 'popup_top'></div>";
var popup_bottom = "<div class = 'popup_bottom'></div>";
var yesNoButtonsDiv = '<div class="popupBtnContainer"><button class="popupBtn" data-type="yes">Yes</button><button class="popupBtn">No</button></div>';

$.fancybox.open({
    padding: 0,
    content: message
});

$('.fancybox-skin').prepend(popup_top);
$('.fancybox-skin').append(popup_bottom);
$('.fancybox-outer').append(yesNoButtonsDiv);

$(document).on('click', '.popupBtn', function() {
    if ($(this).data('type') === 'yes') {
        callback;
    }
    $.fancybox.close();
});
```

}

The problem is, the callback function that i want exacuted, is undefined.

Can anyone help me make this right?

Thank you!

---

the call to openYesNoPopup:

```
openYesNoPopup("Hello World",foo());

function foo(){
    alert("bear");
}
```

for some reason, the alert is shown right on start...

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to actually call it

```
if ($(this).data('type') === 'yes') {
    callback();
}
```

but when calling the `openYesNoPopup` function, you'd reference it, **not** call it

```
openYesNoPopup("Hello World",foo);
```